# A query on ffmpeg's DASH muxer and setting timeShiftBufferDepth values in MPEG-DASH Media Presentation Description (MPD) files

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg-dash

The documentation for the webm_dash_manifest muxer mentions the time_shift_buffer_depth option, defined as "Smallest time (in seconds) shifting buffer for which any Representation is guaranteed to be available. "

What's the equivalent option/setting for the same in the [dash](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#dash-2) muxer (,if implemented) ?

[Documentation for the webm_dash_manifest muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#webm_005fdash_005fmanifest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-window_size <num_segments>` multiplied by the last segment duration appears to set `timeShiftBufferDepth`, when a `SegmentTemplate` is in use.

Source: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/dashenc.c#L922